# React Native dynamic Navigation Menu in a Drawer

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

At the start of my application, I fetch some data from an API.

I want to use the data to create a DrawerNavigator and the number of items in my menu will obviously changed.

What would be the best way to implement this?

Comment: Do objects in from the API response have same structure? If it does, it's better to use the same component and pass each object as parameter. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/nesting#Nesting-a-Navigator-in-a-screen The example shows how to handle users with different names.